# how to connect my mobile phone to google cloud virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to develop android app in google cloud's virtual machine,

I am not able to connect my phone to the google cloud's virtual machine.

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android applications communicate through HTTP or HTTPS. So, you need to have an HTTP server.

You can achieve this by installing Apache and programming a REST API in your Google Cloud Compute Engine (Virtual Machine).

**On a side note:**

I suggest you use Firebase, though. It will allow you to avoid maintaining your own server, and just program with Android. The rest are just configuring Firebase settings.

Comment: Ok I have this question I have asked this question on stackoverflow, they deleted it. So I am you here.. If I learn firebase do I still need to learn JAVA? My question is, Is firebase replacing java for back end development for android...

Comment: If you learn Firebase, you'll have to learn Java for your Android app, and also other settings inside Firebase. Firebase has a Java library for your Android app. You have to learn to use it.